# What are the risks of using a remote node through the Tor and a node hidden service?

Tags: security, tor, attack, remote-node

How insecure is the use of remote nodes, but through the Tor and tor hidden services(remote node with .onion domain)?
What are the possible attacks?
How much damage can it do?
Hope for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar question and [answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/11306/7493).

Using Tor only lessens the risks associated with using a 3rd party remote node. If the node is not yours, you are *trusting* the data it gives you.